# Rails Filter Out Deleted Records in Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My rails app needs to do a 'soft' delete of certain records so they are inactivated without actually being removed from the DB.  Currently I have it implemented with an "is_deleted" flag.

My question is whether there's a best practice for handling associations involving this model.  For example:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessible :is_deleted
  scope :active, -> { where(is_deleted:false) }  
  belongs_to :bar   
end

class Bar
   has_many :foos
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how to set up the Bar model, knowing that it usually deals only with 'active' foos.

I have come up with a couple ideas, and would like to know if there are any pros/cons for using one over the other.

- Use a "condition" qualifier on the has_many declaration to filter out deleted items.
- Create a "active_foos" method on Bar to return only the undeleted items.
- Just use the "[acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/acts_as_paranoid)" gem.  It feels a little heavyweight for what I need, but perhaps it's easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

techwineet's suggestion is decent. But for current code, the simplest solution is to set "active" as default scope if you need to deal with that often.

```
class Foo
  attr_accessible :is_deleted
  default_scope   -> { where(is_deleted:false) }  
  scope :active,  -> { where(is_deleted:false) }
  scope :deleted, -> { where(is_deleted:true) }
  belongs_to :bar   
end

class Bar
   has_many :foos
   # optional delegation
   delegate :active, :delete, to: :foos, prefix: true
end

Foo.all           #=> Return active foos. Or better to use Foo.scoped
Foo.deleted       #=> Return all deleted foos
Foo.unscoped      #=> Return all foos, both active and deleted

bar = Bar.first
bar.foos          #=> Return associated active foos
bar.foos.active   #=> Return associated active foos
bar.foos.deleted  #=> Return associated deleted foos
bar.foos.unscoped #=> Return all associated foos

# Optional delegation
bar.foos_active   #=> Return associated active foos
bar.foos_deleted  #=> Return associated deleted foos
```

Answer (score 3):

The third option to use acts_as_paranoid is best, as it takes up most of the heavyweight lifting and it also gives you other options to load all records whether deleted or deleted after some timestamp. Its better to use already written and tested code then re-inventing the wheel yourself.

Over the period of time, as your app grow, you'll need more & more options and customized queries over the soft deleted records. So, go with acts_as_paranoid.